# invalid connection when using ggplot2 in rmarkdown

Tags: r, ggplot2, connection, r-markdown, knitr

even a simple histogram such as I have included in the rmarkdown code below:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(ggplot2)
mtcars <- mtcars
p <- ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(x=mpg))
p + geom_histogram()
```
````

returns the histogram in the rmarkdown window, but in the console returns:

> Error in isIncomplete(con) : invalid connection
>
> Error in isIncomplete(con) : invalid connection
>
> Error in isIncomplete(con) : invalid connection

this error is returned three times. I am not sure what could be closing the connections, or perhaps it's something different all together. Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you knitting this rmarkdown in a directory you don't have write access to?

Comment: this is just running the code within rmarkdown, not even trying to write to a directory, but when i do write to a directory it is one that i have write access to

Comment: AFAIK, this plot ought not to render given the `include = FALSE` option in the R code chunk. But then I don't think it has anything to do with the problem.

Comment: @Tyler: Have you tried update R and all the packages?

Comment: Yes, everything is up to date. I'm still trying to get to the bottom of it